# Error connecting to Amazon EMR master node

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns

I created an EMR cluster on AWS and it generates my master DNS. I can see the status on the EMR cluster says `Waiting Cluster ready`. I've installed jupyter in this cluster and it is ready.

I also set up the tunnels via putty and I can see the big EMR appears on the screen.

I also use the foxyproxy and it is running.

However, in the last step, when I open a web browser and type my master DNS followed by :8888, it just said `This site can't be reached: xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com took too long to respond`.

This really drives me crazy. I've tried it twice, I can set up the cluster and pay the money but cannot work on that.

Comment: So, you are saying that you can successfully PuTTy into the Master Node (with the big "EMR" text display) but you can't connect to Hue on port 8888? It sounds like a FoxyProxy configuration issue. Can you show us how it is configured?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If FoxyProxy doesn't seem to be doing the job, there's an alternative configuration you can use.

Rather than using FoxyProxy (which forwards all ports), you can redirect specific ports, such as 8888 for Hue. In PuTTy, configure:

- **Source Port:** `8888` (your local port)
- **Destination:** `localhost:8888` (That's the remote machine's `localhost`)

[image: PuTTy tunnel configuration]

Once connected, point your local web browser to `localhost:8888`. This will go through the PuTTy tunnel to the remote machine's `localhost:8888` (as configured in PuTTy), which should connect you to Hue.

Multiple ports can be configured in this way too.

Comment: Thank you so much!  You are right. After that I did succeed once by uninstall my foxyproxy and then reinstall it. That worked once.Now this time I use your method. It works!

Comment: Great! The benefit of FoxyProxy is that it can redirect *all* ports for the remote machines, but it does take a lot of installation and setup. If you just want one port, then the above method is much simpler. Another option is to open port 8888 in the security group but restrict it to your IP address. Then, just access the instance directly from your web browser. That's a little less secure, but users still need to authenticate to access Hue.

Answer (score 1):

AWS Route53 has been having issues for the last 24 hours. [AWS Status](https://status.aws.amazon.com/)
You have to wait until it is resolved. Lot of people are frustrated. It has been 18 hours and they have not resolved it yet.

> ChangeResourceRecordSets Request Throttling
>
> 04:44 PM PDT We are investigating slow propagation of DNS edits to the
>   Route 53 DNS servers. This does not impact queries to existing DNS
>   records.
>
> 10:30 AM PDT We continue to throttle some ChangeResourceRecordSets API
>   calls while we make progress towards recovery. Retries for throttled
>   requests should be successful. Queries to existing DNS records remain
>   unaffected.